# Parallelizing a data iterator using dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask

I have implemented a data iterator that takes objects from two `numpy` arrays and does very intensive CPU computations on them before returning them. I want to parallelize this using `Dask`. Here is a simple version of this iterator class:

```
import numpy as np

class DataIterator:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item1, item2 = x[idx], y[idx]
        # Do some very heavy computations here by
        # calling other methods and return  
        return item1, item2

x = np.random.randint(20, size=(20,))
y = np.random.randint(50, size=(20,))

data_gen = DataIterator(x, y)
```

Right now, I iterate over the items using a simple for loop like this:

```
for i, (item1, item2) in enumerate(data_gen):
    print(item1, item2)
```

But this is really really slow. Can someone please help in parallelizing it using dask?

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be done using a class?

Comment: Yes until unless there is no way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use dask.delayed and to decorate the **getitem** method. The alternative is to turn x, y into dask arrays and then do the computation in the **getitem** method using dask.array commands. Since you have not provided details of the heavy computation, the examples below are only for guidance.

Dask.delayed:

```
from dask import delayed
import numpy as np

class DataIterator:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

    @delayed
    def __getitem__(self):
        item1 = x.mean()
        item2 = y.sum()
        # Do some very heavy computations here by
        # calling other methods and return  
        return item1, item2

x = np.random.randint(20, size=(20,))
y = np.random.randint(50, size=(20,))

data_gen = DataIterator(x, y)
x_mean, y_sum = data_gen.__getitem__().compute()
```

Output:

```
x_mean, y_sum
Out[41]: (8.45, 479)
```

Dask.array:

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

class DataIterator:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

    def __getitem__(self):
        item1 = x.mean()
        item2 = y.sum()
        # Do some very heavy computations here by
        # calling other methods and return  
        return item1.compute(), item2.compute()

x = np.random.randint(20, size=(20,))
y = np.random.randint(50, size=(20,))

x = da.from_array(x, chunks = x.shape[0] // 4)
y = da.from_array(y, chunks = y.shape[0] // 4)

data_gen = DataIterator(x, y)
x_mean, y_sum = data_gen.__getitem__()
```

Ouput:

```
x_mean, y_sum
Out[50]: (10.4, 461)
```